# Is there any way to run elasticsearch from nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am working on a project where elasticsearch need to be implemented so for that I am going to elasticsearch folder and running elasticsearch.bat file everytime. So is there any way to automate this.

Comment: There is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch . Would it suit you?

Comment: Tried this, but it also asking for to run elasticsearch.bat. After executing that file code is working fine as normal.

Comment: @AlexG My question is: Is there any other way to automatically execute elasticsearch.bat file from node.js code?

Comment: You may want to check this https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: @AlexG Thanks for the reply, I tried in the second way also which you shared. But there I need to specify path, so path may change in other machine and server. That's why I am sticking to manual way only as of now.